I am trying to reset password using jwt tokens in php. It's working, but I am unable to show the flash messages
I am able to reset the password but no flash message is displayed.
I want that, the messages must be displayed.
I'm setting the flash message function as follows.
I am using the setFlashMessage functions multiple times. It works inside my _auth.php file becasue I am using switch case inside the _auth.php. But here I am directly posting the password on the same file.
I am displaying messages as follows in _header.php
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["flash_message"]) && isset($_SESSION["flash_category"])) {
  $message = $_SESSION["flash_message"];
  $category = $_SESSION["flash_category"];

  if ($category == "success") {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mb-0" role="alert">
      <strong>Success!</strong> '.$message.'
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show mb-0" role="alert">
      <strong>Error!</strong> '.$message.'
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>';
  }

  unset($_SESSION["flash_message"]);
  unset($_SESSION["flash_category"]); 
}
?>

<?php

    function setFlashMessage(string $message, string $category) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["flash_message"] = $message;
        $_SESSION["flash_category"] = $category;
    }

    // Other functions

?>

My code to update the users password
<?php

  // Code to decode token


  // Code to reset password
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $token = $_GET["token"];
    $newPassword1 = $_POST["newPassword1"];
    $newPassword2 = $_POST["newPassword2"];
    $email = $data_arr['email'];

    if (ctype_alnum($newPassword1) || ctype_alpha($newPassword1) || ctype_digit($newPassword1)) {
      setFlashMessage("Password must contain special characters!", "error");
      header('location: '.get_base_url().'reset-password?token='.$token.'');
    } else if ($newPassword1 != $newPassword2) {
      setFlashMessage("Passwords do not match!", "error");
      header('location: '.get_base_url().'reset-password?token='.$token.'');
    } else {
      $hash = password_hash($newPassword1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
      $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `password`='$hash' WHERE `email`='$email'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      if ($result) {
        setFlashMessage("Password reset successfully!", "success");
        header('location: '.get_base_url().'');
      }
    }
  }

?>

